# How to embed "email address" and "password" in source code

Tags: c#

Hi I am writing a code to access my email in C# and was able to get a sample code to help me, but now i'm struggling. I want to know how can i modify the source code bellow to embed my username and password in the it. Currently when running the code gmail requires my consent. I don't want that, I want the source code to have login credentials.. Any form of help is appreciated.

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private UserCredential _credential;
    const string AppName = "LargeMail";

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        GetCredential();

    }

    public async Task<UserCredential> GetCredential()
    {
        var scopes = new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailModify };
        var uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///client_id.json");
        _credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            uri, scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None);
        return _credential;
    }

    private void GetMessagesClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = _credential,
            ApplicationName = AppName,
        });

        UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Messages.List("me");
        request.MaxResults = 4;
        var messsages = request.Execute().Messages;
        MessagesList.ItemsSource = messsages;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard coding your username and password is an awful idea.

Comment: Let me know where you plan to deploy this. Ive always wanted to try stealing someones idenity.

Comment: on a more serious note, you need to look into https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth properly.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP, UWP..? Always tag your question correctly

Answer (score 2):

Hard coding anything like usernames, passwords and other sensitive information isn't just a terrible idea, it is entirely *INSECURE*. All a user needs to do is decompile your application and they have the credentials needed to access your account.

What you really need to do is look at [Googles Authentication API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth)

Once registered with the developer system, you can generate an authorisation token that will allow your application to access the GMail API. On first use it will request you to confirm your username and password, but following on from that you shouldn't need to repeat that step.

Comment: Tbh. they might not even have to decompile it. A simple resource manager might be able to expose it or even through plaintext in a texteditor if you know what to look for.

Comment: @Bauss indeed. Regardless of the method used to extract, its certainly a poor idea to hardcode sensitive information

Comment: Totally agree with you